# phpQuery : how can I filter some nodes?

Tags: php, filtering, reddit, phpquery

I got a little problem here. 
I'm parsing JSON data from Reddit (eg. https://www.reddit.com/r/Chilledout.json); and I need to setup a function that would filter the data to remove every post that does not have a media attribute.

When I found out which nodes I want to remove, **how can I 'unset' them** and return a filtered [phpQuery](https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery) node ?

The code below returns

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type QueryPath\DOMQuery as array
>   in...

PS : Something that can't be changed in my code is that this function receives a phpQuery node; and should return one too.

```
function get_track_nodes($body_node){

    $selector = '>data >children';
    $options = array(
        'omit_xml_declaration'      => true,
        'ignore_parser_warnings'    => true,
        'convert_from_encoding'     => 'auto',
        'convert_to_encoding'       => 'UTF-8'
    );

    $post_nodes = qp( $body_node, null, $options )->find($selector);

    foreach($post_nodes as $key=>$node) {
        $media = qp( $node, null, self::$querypath_options )->find('media')->innerHTML();
        if (!$media) unset($post_nodes[$key]);
    }

    return $post_nodes;
}
```

Comment: I would start by inspecting each value in `$post_nodes`. Try putting `var_dump($node);` in your foreach loop.

Comment: For sure, the thing I can't manage to do is to remove a node when I don't want it.  It's not like a regular array where you can unset() an item...

Comment: Why can't you? Can you not call `list($post_nodes)`?

Comment: I edited the original question with my actual (broken) code and the error it outputs.

Comment: What does your `qp()` function return?